# Регулярное выражение для обработки url

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, url

Всем привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста форумчане, как правильно написать регулярное выражение для обработки `url`?

Допустим `url` - `https://www.someurl.com/`
Надо из него получить только `someurl.com`.

Получить `someurl.com/` получается `let str2 = str.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?(www.)/, '')`, но тут если убрать `www.` регулярка сломается. Пробовал через `|` задавать и слэш, но результатов пока не получил.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: возможно так `'https://www.someurl.com/'.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?((www.)?)/, '')`

Comment: `let q = new URL('https://www.someurl.com/');  console.log(q.host.replace(/^www\./, ''))`

Answer (score 1):

Для надёжности и простоты, можно сначала воспользоваться интерфейсом [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) для парсинга ключевых частей, потом по необходимости допилить регулярками:

```js
const { hostname } = new URL('https://www.someurl.com/');
const hostnameWithoutWWW = hostname.replace(/^www\./, '');
console.log(hostname, hostnameWithoutWWW);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!